# How to change a track ID with ffmpeg or MP4Box?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mp4box

I need to change the id of a video track in an mp4 container and of course without re-encoding. How can I do that with ffmpeg or MP4Box ? Is that even possible ?

Comment: If you mean the order of tracks, then you can just run ffmpeg with streamcopy with `-map` assignments in the order that you want.

Comment: @Mulvya No, I'd like to have only one track, but so that its id would be, for example, 7 (don't ask why). See the accepted answer.

Comment: It is not possible with ffmpeg though (it will number tracks in order of output streams).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MP4Box you can fine-tune these parameters (more in `MP4Box -h general`):

- `-set-track-id id1:id2 changes the id of a track from id1 to id2`
- `-swap-track-id id1:id2 swaps the IDs of the identified tracks`

Example:

- inplace: `MP4Box -set-track-id 100:101 file.mp4`
- new file: `MP4Box -set-track-id 100:101 file.mp4 -out new.mp4`

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.